# Checking if files exist in nested uneven directories?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a program that grabs data from nested directories and then processes them. I thought these directories had an even structure and could just do this to retrieve them:

`val inputPath = basePath + dataSet + "/*/*/*/*/*/"` However, some of the directories are even more nested. For example, let's say we have this directory structure:

`/hello/world/my/name/is/somedatafiles` there can be another directory structure that looks like this: `/hello/world/my/name/is/waldo/somedatafiles`

Is there a way to get to the end of the directory in Scala with an uneven directory structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fragment from Rosettacode.org:

```
import java.io.File

object `package` { 
  def walkTree(file: File): Iterable[File] = {
    val children = new Iterable[File] {
      def iterator = if (file.isDirectory) file.listFiles.iterator else Iterator.empty
    }
    Seq(file) ++: children.flatMap(walkTree(_))
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  val dir = new File("/home/user")
  for(f <- walkTree(dir)) println(f)
  for(f <- walkTree(dir) if f.getName.endsWith(".mp3")) println(f)
}
```

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#Scala

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`walkTree` gives back files **and** directories,
i.e. eventually one can have a directory named .mp3,
so it's better to filter i.e. something like:

```
val dirList = walkTree(f).filter(!isDirectory(_)).map ...
```